# Understanding key-value constructors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, key-value

I am trying to understand type synonyms and how they can be practically used.

This is the type synonym:

```
empty = const Nothing
type KVS a b = a -> Maybe b
```

And I want to make a function to insert a `KVS` pair with the following code:

```
insert k v kvs = \k' -> if k' == k then Just v else kvs k'
```

My question about this code is:

1. What is the `k'` in the lambda? What does it represent?
2. Where is it getting its value from?
3. What is the condition `if k' == k` checking?

I do understand the concepts of `Just` and `Maybe`, but this particular piece of code is what I can't wrap my head around.

An explanation with respect to functional programming would be nice.

Comment: `k'` is the key to lookup.

Comment: `k'` is the `a` in the `a -> Maybe b` type which you've called `KVS`. It's a key whose value you are looking up in `insert k v vs`

Comment: Since from your profile you seem to be familiar with JavaScript, perhaps a transliteration would also help: `var empty = (k) => undefined; var insert = (k, v, kvs) => (k_) => k_ == k ? v : kvs(k_)`. These produce functions that represent a map by returning a value in response to being called with a key, or returning `undefined` if no value has been inserted for that key. An example of usage in JS—`var m = insert("y", 2, insert("x", 1, empty));`, `m("x") === 1`, `m("z") === undefined`—is analogous to the Haskell—`m = insert "y" 2 (insert "x" 1 empty)`, `m "x" == Just 1`, `m "z" == Nothing`.

Comment: "I am trying to understand type synonyms and how they can be practically used." I'm not sure how this relates to the rest of the question, because you don't give any type signatures involving type synonyms. I generally recommend that beginners *avoid* using type synonyms, and that others use them sparingly. They don't actually have much to offer in most cases, beginners tend to think they do more than they can, and they add potentially confusing mental indirection to the code. Until you learn about higher-rank types, type families, or the `Constraint` kind, I suggest you just not bother.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. What is the `k'` in the lambda? What does it represent?

Here your map is just a function that maps a key `k` to a `Maybe v` (value). So `k'` is the parameter in case we perform a lookup.

Note that, as [@AJFarmar says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674254/understanding-key-value-constructors-in-haskell/56674377#comment99916966_56674377), the single quote (`'`) can be used as part of an identifier as well, unlike some (most) languages that use this only as part of a character literal. As the [Haskell'10 report says on *Lexical structure*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4):

> An identifier consists of a letter followed by zero or more letters, digits, underscores, **and single quotes**.

It is frequently used since it mimics the [prime character [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)#Use_in_mathematics,_statistics,_and_science), which is used in mathematics for:

> In mathematics, the prime is generally used to generate more variable names for **things which are similar**, without resorting to subscripts – x′.

> 2. Where is it getting its value from?

The `insert` will not pass a value to `k'`. We simply construct a new function that maps the key `k'` to a `Just v` in case that key is the same as the key we added `k`, or in case that does *not* hold, we call the original map (to make a lookup in the "old" map).

The `empty` map is a `const Nothing`, something that maps everything to `Nothing`, so that means that, regardless what we lookup, we will always retrieve `Nothing`, which is indeed what an empty map is supposed to do.

> 3. What is the condition if `k' == k` checking?

In case of a lookup, it checks if the key we lookup is the same as the key of the key-value pair `(k, v)` we just inserted. In case that holds, we thus return a `Just v`, otherwise, we make a call to the old map.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that adding `'` at the end of a variable name is allowed in Haskell, as it mimics [the ‘prime’ symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) often used in mathematics. This could cause confusion as in most languages the quotation mark is reserved only for strings and characters.